# Frustrating error when trying to use MySQL Update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Really quick but frustrating issue that I cannot seem to figure out!

I have a MySQL Query like this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE jobs SET first_name = 'Borge' WHERE jobno='12313'");
```

And that works but as soon as I try and do this to put the actual values in it doesn't work.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE jobs SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE jobno='$jobno'");
```

If someone could help me out that would be awesome!

Comment: You should use prepared statements. Also show us what error you get.

Comment: echo "UPDATE jobs SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE jobno='$jobno'"   this, and run this query in your sql\

Comment: What are the values of `$first_name` and `$jobno`

Comment: Well I just changed by query to this `if (!mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE jobs SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE jobno='$jobno'"))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }` And now its working? I don't know why

Comment: `$first_name = "owned"; $jobno = "1' OR 1 = 1 --";` - what's going to happen? Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE jobs SET first_name = '$first_name' WHERE jobno=$jobno");
```

please try this query it will help you and also add mysql_error(); at the end of your query it will help you to figure out the issue.